# Problems in passing url variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, urlvariables

I have a code for a shopping cart, which uses sessions to store the cart info for visitors/guests.

I dont want visitors to make an account and login just for adding a few items into cart, so that's the reason for the guest cart using sessions.

I used php and the problem is that it is not secure because I am passing product id through the url.

Also when the cart quantity is updated, more values pass through the url.

### The links bellow are .text files of the code I am using

https://jameshamilton.eu/sites/default/files/products.txt

### https://jameshamilton.eu/sites/default/files/cart.txt

if someone goes to the cart page and looks at the url, (the url looks like this >>>> www.mywebsite.whatever/cart.php?action=remove&id=2
 ) ,and refreshes the cart page when an item is added to cart, the item will keep increasing in quantity just by refreshing the page.

---

### Is this a real problem? if so how can it be countered?

I was thinking of setting up a session that is auto incremented with random integers (so that it cant be guessed).

The session starts immediately when a user/visitor visits the website and it is inserted into the MySQL database using the auto incremented value from the session.

From then on, anything that the user/visitor adds to cart goes directly into the mysql database table under the session value.

So, the cart items will be displayed by retreating the items added to the database table WHERE the session = session value.

once the user leaves the page the session will be destroyed and the session integer/value added to the database will be deleted also

is this a good approach? are there much simpler and safer ways to implement a guest shopping cart

### **Product**

```
<?php
    //connect to your database here
?>

</head>

<body>


<table border="1">

    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT id, name, description, price FROM php_shop_products;";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while(list($id, $name, $description, $price) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>$name</td>";
                echo "<td>$description</td>";
                echo "<td>$price</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$id\">Add To Cart</a></td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }

    ?>
</table>


<a href="cart.php">View Cart</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**cart**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>



<?php
    //connect to your database here
?>


</head>
<body>


<?php

    $product_id = $_GET[id];     //the product id from the URL 
    $action     = $_GET[action]; //the action from the URL 

    //if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message
    if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
        die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
    }

    switch($action) {   //decide what to do 

        case "add":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        break;

        case "remove":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
            if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
        break;

        case "empty":
            unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
        break;

    }

?>


<?php   

    if($_SESSION['cart']) { //if the cart isn't empty
        //show the cart

        echo "<table border=\"1\" padding=\"3\" width=\"40%\">";    //format the cart using a HTML table

            //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and $quantity is the value
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {    

                //get the name, description and price from the database - this will depend on your database implementation.
                //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
                $sql = sprintf("SELECT name, description, price FROM php_shop_products WHERE id = %d;",
                                $product_id); 

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                    list($name, $description, $price) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                    $line_cost = $price * $quantity;        //work out the line cost
                    $total = $total + $line_cost;           //add to the total cost

                    echo "<tr>";
                        //show this information in table cells
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
                        //along with a 'remove' link next to the quantity - which links to this page, but with an action of remove, and the id of the current product
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$product_id\">X</a></td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$line_cost</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";

                }

            }

            //show the total
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\">Total</td>";
                echo "<td align=\"right\">$total</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            //show the empty cart link - which links to this page, but with an action of empty. A simple bit of javascript in the onlick event of the link asks the user for confirmation
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";       
        echo "</table>";



    }else{
        //otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
        echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";

    }

    //function to check if a product exists
    function productExists($product_id) {
            //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
            $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM php_shop_products WHERE id = %d;",
                            $product_id); 

            return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > 0;
    }
?>

<a href="products.php">Continue Shopping</a>


<?php

/*

products table:
    CREATE TABLE `products` (
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        `name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
        `description` TEXT,
        `price` DOUBLE DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
    );

*/

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not as links to your site.

Comment: PHP session IDs are random strings, they're already hard to guess.

Comment: case "add":
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;

Comment: $quantity<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$product_id\">X</a>

Comment: Barmar. Okay well that is great, so is it a good approach to follow?
to incert the random strings into the sql

Comment: You don't need to put anything into the SQL. Just use PHP session variables, and PHP takes care of it for you.

Comment: I have done that, and I have posted my code above :).
But my worry is that, the quantity can be changed using the url product id
is that a real concern?

Comment: Don't put the quantity in the URL, keep it in a session variable.

Comment: would you be able to show me in an example?